# echo variable containing html and the_permalink();

Tags: php, permalinks, html

I'am trying to echo a vriable, but the permalink does not work as clickable button. The permalink just displayed outside the button.

Here is my code:

```
$perma = the_permalink();

$valid = '<button class="btn btn-success btn-wide" href="'.$perma.'">
           Gegevens opgeslagen  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
           <a class="pull-right"><span class="label label-default">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></span></a></p>  
          </button>';


$id = get_the_ID();

if($id == '2440'){
        if($current_user->google_play_gebruikersnaam != ""){
                echo $valid;
              }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`get_permalink()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink), which will *return* the URL as opposed to echo'ing it.

Comment: Oke that solves one problem, can you explain to me wy the permalink doesnt work with <button> and only with <a>?

Comment: Nevermind i fixed it!